# Length of list pattern

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have a list where I am trying to find the sum of combination of the lists entries, except the entries where both values to add are equal to each other (ie 2+2 would not be added) and add them to another list.
As an example:

```
[1,2,3] would yield the list of sums [3,4,5] because 1+2=5,1+3=4, and 2+3=5
```

However, my issues arises with not knowing how many sums will be produced. I am working in java and am limited to native arrays, therefore the size of the array has to be set before I can add the sum values to it.

I know I would not be able to find the exact size of the sum list due to the possibility that a sum would not get added if the two elements are the same, but I am trying to ballpark it so I don't have massive arrays.

The closest 'formula' I have gotten is setting the following, but it is never precisely what the max value would be for any list

```
(list length of original numbers * list length of original numbers) / 2
```

I am trying to keep time complexity in mind, so keeping a running count of how many sums there are, setting an array to that size, and looping through the original list again would not be efficient.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about initializing a `boolean` array with `max(lst)*2` elements, then settings those to `true` where the sum can be reached? (assuming `max(lst)` is relatively small and not in the millions)

Comment: To clarify: You are always adding two numbers, not more of two? And by "not the same", you mean the numbers to add or the result? And can the array contain duplicate numbers? What would be the result for `[1,2,3,4]`? `[3,4,5,5,6,7]` or just `[3,4,5,6,7]`?

Comment: For no duplicate numbers but equal results being okay, there would _always_ be `n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1` = `n(n-1)/2` combinations of two numbers for a list of `n` elements.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful replies, n(n-1)/2 was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add same sums to array, I mean, your array is {1,2,3,4,5}. Would you print the both result of 1+5 and 2+4 =6.
If your answer is yes. You can get the length of array and multiply it with 1 less and divide them to 2. For instance; our array → {1,2,3,4,5} the lenght is 5 the length of our result array will be 5*4/2=10.

Or you can use lists in java if you cant define a length for array. Keep in mind.

Comment: (Length * length-1) / 2 was exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Was so close in my original formula